# Encrypted MySQL Connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have to encrypt a connection between a PHP script one one server to a MySQL database on another server.  What is the best way to do this using PHP?  I'm open to any encryption method.

Thanks!

Comment: [Setup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-connections.html) and [connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an SSL connection.

Here's a link to the official documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-connections.html

Comment: perfect.  That link led me to this site which looks promising, though I haven't tested it yet- http://www.madirish.net/?article=244.  Thanks